# Magento 1.9.24 upgrade - reset password issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I upgrade my magento store to the last version, after this I can't reset the customer passsword in frontend, so:

1. I press on Forgot Your Password button
2. Complete with my email password and press Submit
3. In the received email I press on "RESET PASSWORD" button and I am redirected to the store and I have this error: **Your password reset link has expired.**

How I can solve this?

Comment: Please refer this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84605/magento-reset-password-link-not-working-after-upgrade

Comment: in your In your template customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml file check for <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: also refer this http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/11/03/reset-password-blank-page-magento-1-9-2-2/

definatly you will get solution

Comment: hi no one of this not working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hi, 
how you identify is this is not programming-related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I had the same, but a second error message appeared 
which said that a required field is not filled out. 
In general: when anything goes wrong when saving the customer, 
the said error message "Your password reset link has expired" shows up. 
So, pay attention to any additional error messages showing up or in your log files.

If you want to find out what's happening in detail, 
go to the file 
"app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php" 
and modify the method resetPasswordPostAction temporarily. 
Inside the } catch (Exception $exception) { directive, add Mage::logException($e);. 
After you have seen the error again, 
you can find the real error message in the file var/log/exception.log.
```

Ref Link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84605/magento-reset-password-link-not-working-after-upgrade

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I do this, but I can't see anything in the var/log/exception.log, I have only two errors:

Notice: Undefined index: items  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 166


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 166